# Inside tkinter notebook, ttk widget not responding

Tags: python, tkinter

In my application I have a main frame. Then make a login frame inside the main frame.

Then make a notebook frame inside the login Frame.

**But inside the notebook frame, ttk combobox, butoon are not showing as per ttk style.**

*It show as the default comboBox, default button.*

Here the code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import askyesno

root = Tk()

root.geometry("500x500+10+10")

main_frame = Frame(root)
# main_frame.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
# main_frame.pack_propagate(False)
main_frame.configure(width=2000, height=1400)
main_frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)


login_frame1 = Frame(main_frame)
login_frame1.configure(width=2000, height=1400)
login_frame1.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)


COLOR_GREEN = "#996666"
COLOR_select = "#b3cccc"

# style for notebook tab
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_create("yummy", parent="alt", settings={ 
"TNotebook": {"configure": {"tabmargins": [2, 5, 2, 0] } },
"TNotebook.Tab": {
"configure": {"padding": [5, 1], "background": COLOR_GREEN, "font" : ('times', '11', 'bold')},
"map":       {"background": [("selected", COLOR_select)],
"expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])] } } } )

style.configure("yummy", focuscolor=style.configure(".")["background"])
style.theme_use("yummy")


# global notebook
notebook = ttk.Notebook(login_frame1)
notebook.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

frame_color = 'white'
input_color = '#c7d1d1'

label_font = ('calibri',12, 'bold')
input_font = ('times',12)


tab1 = Frame(notebook, bg=frame_color)
tab2 = Frame(notebook, bg=frame_color)
tab1.pack(expand=True, fill= BOTH)

# Add tab1 frame into notebook
notebook.add(tab1, text='Table 1')
notebook.add(tab2, text='Table 2')
notebook.select(tab1) 

txt = 'Table View'
lbl = Label(tab1, text=txt, font=('Gloss And Bloom',20,'bold'),  fg='red', bg='white')
lbl.place(x=80, y=5, relwidth=1, height=45)

combo = ttk.Combobox(tab1)
combo.place(x=10, y=15)

btn = ttk.Button(tab1, text='Click me', width=20)
btn.place(x=10, y=50)




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It this is what you want? https://ibb.co/cN2xLD4

Comment: The code seems to work fine for me. Also, your question is unclear. The title says widgets don't respond, but in the body you seem to be asking about colors.

Comment: @toyotaSupra  No. Look at the code, here I'm using `ttk.Combobox` . But in the **output** it look like **default Combobox, not ttk.Combobox.**

Comment: What do you mean default combobox? I'm using ttk.combobox and ttk.Button, etc. Please edit your question..