# Get a full black Tab with ttk

Tags: tkinter, header, themes, ttk

[Tab Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoQbX.png)

Hi everybody,

I created a tab with Tkinter ttk (so far nothing special). Each of the three tabs has a label and a slider.

I tried several options with Style to get rid off the ugly white edges - I need the borders and the tab headers in black, too. Can anybody tell me how I can get this?

Thanks in advance!

[Change color of "tab header" in ttk.Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038356/change-color-of-tab-header-in-ttk-notebook)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried so far