# Customising ttk.Frame widget

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I want to be able to adjust the color of a `ttk.Frame()` widget. I know this question has been asked numerous times here. A very useful answer was given here: [Change color of "tab header" in ttk.Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038356/change-color-of-tab-header-in-ttk-notebook). One can do this using `style.theme_create()`.

I want to make a similar adjustment using `ttk.Style()` but cannot figure out how. Could someone explain to me how I can do this?

The reason I am not using the method proposed in the above link is because there are other widgets in my code that I want to (and can) customize using `ttk.Style()`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Window():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.minsize(width=600, height=400)
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):   
        s1 = ttk.Style()
        s1.configure('My.TNotebook.Tab', padding=5, background='red')
        s1.map('My.TNotebook.Tab', background=[('selected', 'green')])

        self.nb1 = ttk.Notebook(self.parent, style='My.TNotebook.Tab')
        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.nb1)        
        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.nb1)
        self.tab3 = ttk.Frame(self.nb1)   
        self.nb1.add(self.tab1, text='Tab1')
        self.nb1.add(self.tab2, text='Tab2')
        self.nb1.add(self.tab3, text='Tab3')
        self.nb1.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, width=500, height=200)
        self.b1 = ttk.Button(self.parent, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        self.b1.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.7, height=70, width=150)

    def quit(self):
        self.parent.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29572789/355230) might help you.

Comment: If you need to change the color of a frame, why not use the standard tkinter `Frame`? It's very easy to change the color of it.

Comment: @martineau you are right, although it looks a little too complicated. I was really hoping there's a chance to simply use `ttk.Style.configure()`. I'll look into that answer.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I guess I didn't express myself properly. What I need is to be able to change the style of `ttk.Notebook` tabs. My initial guess was to do something to `ttk.Frame` since this is how tabs are constructed.

Comment: Duplicate of [ttk styling “TNotebook.Tab” background and borderwidth not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22389198/291641) possibly given the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

I searched more and found an interesting and simple solution here: http://page.sourceforge.net/html/themes.html. The key to solving the problem seems to be the need to tell Python which theme to use (I am running Python on Windows). In my answer, I use `classic` but `winnative`, `clam`, `alt`, and `default` will do too. Using `vista` or `xpnative` makes no effect on the tabs' colors.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Window():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.minsize(width=600, height=400)
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):   
        s1 = ttk.Style()
        s1.theme_use('classic')
        s1.configure('TNotebook.Tab', background='navajo white')
        s1.map('TNotebook.Tab', background=[('selected', 'goldenrod'), ('active', 'goldenrod')])

        self.nb1 = ttk.Notebook(self.parent)
        self.nb1.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, width=500, height=200)
        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.nb1)        
        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.nb1)
        self.tab3 = ttk.Frame(self.nb1)
        self.nb1.add(self.tab1, text='Tab1')
        self.nb1.add(self.tab2, text='Tab2')
        self.nb1.add(self.tab3, text='Tab3')
        self.b1 = ttk.Button(self.parent, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        self.b1.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.7, height=70, width=150)

    def quit(self):
        self.parent.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```